# Why NSOperation starts before completion previous operation?

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I'm trying the next:

1. I get response from Alamofire, fill an array
2. print this array

for this I did:

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()

let firstOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {
    let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
     Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.userParameters.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
         do {
              let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
              print(json)

              if json["user"].count > 0 {
                  self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
              }
          }
      }
})

firstOperation.completionBlock = {
     print("firstOperation completed")
}

queue.addOperation(firstOperation)

let secondOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {
     print(self.profileDetails)
})

secondOperation.addDependency(firstOperation.completionBlock)

secondOperation.completionBlock = {
    print(self.profileDetails)
}

queue.addOperation(secondOperation)
```

So, in the theory, at first it needs to fill my array, complete this task(block) and just later print those array. But I get:

```
firstOperation completed
[] -> self.profileDetails from the secondOperation
[] -> self.profileDetails from the secondOperation completion block
and just here I get my JSON from the Alamofire 'do' block
```

So, what I did wrong? And how can I fix it that it will work as I want?

Comment: Your block returns (and thus the operation completes) as soon as the request goes out, it won't wait for an asynchronous call to come back.

Comment: Is there any solution for it? I want to get full array before I'll start print it @dan

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the second operation until after the first operation completes (e.g. at the end of the first operations block).

Comment: So I need to add this line 'queue.addOperation(secondOperation)'  after the Alamofire closure?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to understand that `Alamofire` request is always performed in a separate thread.

So your `firstOperation` is useless. You do not need it because Alamofire is already asynchronous.

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()

let secondOperation = NSBlockOperation(block: {
    print(self.profileDetails)
})


secondOperation.completionBlock = {
    print(self.profileDetails)
}

let getMyProfileURL = "\(self.property.host)\(self.property.getMyProfile)"
Alamofire.request(.POST, getMyProfileURL, parameters: self.userParameters.profileParameteres, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON { response in
    do {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        print(json)

        if json["user"].count > 0 {
            self.profileDetails.append(ProfileDetailsModel(json: json["user"]))
        }
    }

    print("Alamofire.request completed") // instead of: print("firstOperation completed")

    queue.addOperation(secondOperation)
}
```